# how to fetch a single column value from a datatable

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a table

```
Login(id(int),EmailId(varchar(35),connType(varchar))
```

where conntype has values like pop3 or imap. consider an user is loggedin. i want to fetch connType value of the logged user to do like this

```
if(conntypeValue == imap)
{
 //code for imap connection
}else
{
//code for pop3 connection
}
```

how can i do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above there is a lot of documentation covering this.  There are many ways to connect to a database and retrieve information such as Linq2Sql and NHibernate.  I've done it with the basic SqlConnection classes.  Personally I feel it's important to understand these concepts first.

```
public SqlConnectionExample()
    {
        // the connection string to the database - this should ALWAYS be configurable
        string connectionString = "server=localhost;initial catalog=mydatabase; user=mysqluser;pass=mysqlpassword";
        int userID = 1; // the ID of the logged in user

        // create a connection to the database
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            // create a command to pass over the connection
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select connType from login where ID = @id", conn))
            {
                // create a SQL parameter to add them to the command - this will limit the results to the single user
                SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                p.Value = userID;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(p);

                // as we are only selecting one column and one row we can use ExecuteScalar
                string connType = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                if (connType.Equals("imap", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    // imap
                }
                else
                {
                    // pop3
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

You will need to determine the correct ConnectionString (try www.connectionstrings.com) and UserID yourself.  Note if you're expecting more than a single row returned (I'm assuming ID is the Primary Key here) you'll need to use a SqlDataReader with the cmd.ExecuteReader function.

Notice also I'm using string.Equals() rather than connType == "Imap", this is to allow me to specify case insensitivity.

Hope this helps